# Remove Windows service from command line

Tags: windows, services

I would like to do this because I have a half installed service because of installation failure which is just there, non-functioning.

How can I delete the Windows service using the command line?

Comment: Related post - [How can I delete a service in Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76074/465053)

Answer (score 39):

NOTE: You'll likely need an elevated command prompt (right click => "Run as Administrator") to execute this command

the [`sc`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490995.aspx) command is what you want, specifically `sc delete`

```
C:\Users\Jeff>sc delete
DESCRIPTION:
        Deletes a service entry from the registry.
        If the service is running, or another process has an
        open handle to the service, the service is simply marked
        for deletion.
USAGE:
        sc  delete [service name]
```

Comment: If you're in powershell, you'll want to make sure to type `sc.exe` because sc in powershell gets you the Set-Content cmdlet which will quietly look like it might have worked.

Answer (score 14):

We need to stop the service before deleting it from the Registry:

```
sc stop [Service name]  
sc delete [service name]
```

Run Command prompt as an administrator and execute above commands.

Enclose the service name in double quotes if it contains spaces.

Comment: Just as an fyi, `sc stop` might not be finished stopping when `sc delete` runs, which can cause problems. It's not a common problem, but some services take a while to wind down. I'm not sure if I've run into this problem at straight commandline, but I definitely have when invoking service removal APIs for a couple a languages.

Answer (score -1):

Simply put quotation marks between any service name that contain spaces
C:\WINDOWS\system32>sc delete "Your Ugly Service"

Comment: It would have been better to suggest an edit to one of the existing answers to include the helpful information about double-quoting service names with spaces.