# How Top Stop Programs Starting Up Using Command Prompt In Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, command-line, boot

I want to stop a program from starting in Windows 7 using command prompt. This is on a PC where I cannot access msconfig and cannot install programs, but I can use command prompt.

Is this possible and if so, how?

Comment: The question is unclear: do you mean prevent programs from running at boot time, e.g. those linked in the Startup folders, or prevent a *specific* program from being run by the user?

Comment: Yes, I want to stop a program from booting up when Windows starts. I would normally do this from msconfig, but I can't access that so I need to use command prompt, if that's possible.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your needs, you could try the following at a CMD prompt:

1. **DEL *filename*** -- that program will never run again
2. If it's a [Windows Service](https://superuser.com/questions/460076/disable-a-windows-service-from-the-command-line):

   **sc stop *service name***

   **sc config *service name* start= disabled**
3. If it's a [Windows Scheduled Task](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc766529.aspx):

   **schtasks.exe /Change /TN *task name* /Disable**

There are yet other ways to start a task automatically; you need to be more specific about your issue.

Answer (score 0):

You could connect remotely to that computer, given that you have the necessary  credentials. When connecting against it using regedit  you could open the key hklm\software\Microsoft\windows\currentversion\run  and delete the software you don't want to start.

Regedit has an option to connect to that computer remotely on the file menu.

Answer (score 0):

To stop a program from starting up you can use the REG command line tool to query and delete.  Try "Reg /?" to get started.

Reg query hklm\software\microsoft\windows\currentversion\run
Reg delete hklm\software\microsoft\windows\currentversion\run /v HotKeyCmds

Note: To delete the registry key you will need to run the Command Prompt window in Administrator Mode.