# Stop and disable windows service from command line

Tags: windows-7, command-line

I've tried the top comment here [Disable a Windows service from the command line](https://superuser.com/questions/460076/disable-a-windows-service-from-the-command-line) but when I restart the computer the service is back up and running again.

If I manually go into services.msc and change the Startup type to "Disabled", change the Service Status to "Stop" and then Click "Apply" and then "OK", after rebooting the computer it is still disabled.

This is the commands I am issuing

```
sc stop "igfxCUIService1.0.0.0"
sc config "igfxCUIService1.0.0.0" start= disabled
```

And the following is the logging

```
SERVICE_NAME: igfxCUIService1.0.0.0 
    TYPE               : 10  WIN32_OWN_PROCESS  
    STATE              : 3  STOP_PENDING 
                            (STOPPABLE, NOT_PAUSABLE, IGNORES_SHUTDOWN)
    WIN32_EXIT_CODE    : 0  (0x0)
    SERVICE_EXIT_CODE  : 0  (0x0)
    CHECKPOINT         : 0x0
    WAIT_HINT          : 0x0
[SC] ChangeServiceConfig SUCCESS
```

Comment: This reads like an answer to the other question or a comment on an answer there rather than a new question.  What is your question?

Answer (score 1):

Is this being done from an elevated (admin) command prompt? If not then launch cmd.exe as an administrator and rerun your commands and reboot again.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried MSCONFIG?

1. <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> -> `msconfig` -> <kbd>ENTER</kbd>
2. go to tab "Services"
3. Untick your service